# Binding promise data to $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have  designed a factory that gets data from a url and returns it  to the controller.
In the controller i make a call to this factory.
I've used $q to resolve promise.
When calling the factory from the controller I am trying to assign the returned value to the scope.
After assigning the value when i try to access the value in scope i get the message undefined
Could you please help me resolve this issue

```
app.factory('barchart', function($http,$q) {
    var factory={};
    factory.drawChart=function() {  
        var deferred=$q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'ActionServlet',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            params: {country: "densityplot"}
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // something went wrong :(
        });
        return deferred.promise;
        };
    return factory;
});

app.controller('mycontroller',function($scope, $http, barchart) {
    var promise = barchart.drawChart();
    console.log("Promise " + promise);
    promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.barChartData = data;
        console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
    });
        console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
});
```

But when its inside the scope it displays the data.
Whenever I try to print the value outside the promises scope it gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

[Angular's $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) performs async operations. Your `then` as below

```
promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.barChartData = data;
    console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
});
```

receives the data onces `$http` is done with its async operation. It puts data in a variable and prints it and all works fine.

However when you try to log outside of that scope

```
promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.barChartData = data;
    console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
});
console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
```

`$http` is not done with its operation yet, therefore `$scope.barChartData` is still undefined.

Your `then` just tells the controller what to do when the promise is received from the factory. Just because that piece of code is above the seperate log doesn't mean it gets called in that order.

Comment: Is it possible to synchronize the above code? Like the scope should be assigned the value from promise only after it has been received from remote server?

Comment: @kais That it what `then` function does, it is executed when the service is done with the remote call and returns the promise to the controller

Comment: What i need is the value from promise should be available in the sequence in which code is written.As i want the value in scope to be tested in jasmine

Comment: When i try to access the same scope variable in jasmine it says undefined.So somehow can i delay by some time so that data gets assigned to scope and  is accessible immediately?

Comment: @kais Testing services that return promises is an entirely different subject, it's better to create a seperate question for that. At least you know why it's not doing what you expected it to do, so you can work from there :-)

Comment: Can i delay the assignment to scope ? what i want is the value should get displayed in console immediately after getting assigned in then.But its not happening.Somehow i want to synchroonize it

Comment: @kais You probably want to log `console.log("barchart data " + data);` in the `then`..what provides the promise, barChartData.getSVG or barchart.DrawChart?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the console statement outside the scope of the promise is fired before the promise is returned... Hence undefined...

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, barchart) {        
    barchart.drawChart()
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.barChartData = data;
            console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
        });

    console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
});
```

A side not as well... is your $http service actually returning an object of functions? This seems weird but not impossible:

```
$scope.barChartData.getSVG();
```

If you are confused about the way [asynchronousity](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/) of [JS](http://www.slideshare.net/clutchski/writing-asynchronous-javascript-101) works you should read further up on the subject, but in a nutshell your code it running like this. Not taking the

1. barchart.drawChart()
2. $http(); //factory function
3. console.log("Promise " + promise);
4. console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG()); //The one outside the then()
5. some potential waiting time while we wait for the http req as its asynchronous we never know the exact time it will take to return the value - this is where the promise shines!
6. then()
7. $scope.barChartData = data; //inside the promise
8. console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG()); //Inside the promise

You said in a comment you would like this outside to fire when the promise is returned well you can accomplish this with another promise.

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $q, barchart) {        
     var requestFinished = $q.defer();

     barchart.drawChart()
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.barChartData = data;
            console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
            requestFinished.resolve();
        });

     requestFinished.promise.then(function() {
         console.log("barchart data " + $scope.barChartData.getSVG());
     });
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to synchronize the above code?     Like the scope should be assigned the value from promise only after it has been received from remote server?

Comment: But its not working the way i want it to.Its not displaying in console the immediate statement outside then.I want it data to get displayed immediately after assignment outside then.Is is possible?